# apt-get -y install apache2 not working!

Tags: apt, server, apache2

I am new to docker and i was trying to update Ubuntu and install Apache 2 on an Ubuntu container as well with dockerfile commands but this error on the attached image keeps showing up.

How do I get this fixed? Here is the error message:

[image: screenshot of terminal outut]

My dockerfile instructions are below:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
ADD . /var/www/html
ENTRYPOINT apachectl -D FOREGROUND
ENV name Pope..
```

Comment: docker is not apt? I don't think that docker has apache2, I would run `apt install -y apache2`

Comment: Hello. I think it depends on your version of the ubuntu docker image. Try it with `ubuntu:latest` in your Dockerfile and then rebuild it again.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages